# How to disable image post processing with Paperclip but allow custom post processor?

Tags: ruby, paperclip

I need to enable a custom post-processor for Paperclip but prevent the regular image post processing from occurring. (I am using Paperclip to upload files that are not images, so the image post processing is not needed but I have a post processing routine specific to my files that does need to run.)

The typical way I have seen to disable post processing for Paperclip disables ALL post processing by using the before_post_process callback.

Is there a way I can disable the image post processing but still run mine?